# How to add custom rules to "StyleCop by Resharper"?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, resharper, stylecop

**Problem:**

My company recently decided to improve coding standards. One of the proposals has been to add a blank line after an 'if' statement withput brackets. E.g.:

```
if(condition)
    statement;

statement;
```

This kind of construct is widely used in our codebase and adding a blank line would increase readability. Now it is my job to find a way to bring VS13 to indicate this in inspection.

**Attempted Solutions:**

At first I tried to solve this by using Resharper.

In `Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Blank Lines` is no such option available.

A pattern (added in `Code Inspection -> Custom Patterns`) does find the 'if' statements just fine but I cannot add a blank line as this is, according to the Internet, out of scope of that functionality.

At that point I searched for another solution and found StyleCop. The first Version I tried was 'StyleCop by Resharper' ([here](https://github.com/StyleCop/StyleCop.ReSharper)). As far as I can tell StyleCop does not support this feature either. But [there](https://github.com/Visual-Stylecop/Visual-StyleCop) is documentation explaining how to add custom rules in another Version of Stylecop. So I thought that something like this might also be possible in 'StyleCop by Resharper'. But unfortunately there is no documentation anywhere.

I then used Visual StyleCop and removed the Resharper Version. I also downloaded the [VisualStudio Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ChristopheHEISER.VisualStyleCop) for Visual StyleCop and implemented my custom rule. The extension even found said rule... but it did not mark anything in my solution and manual scans were cancelled early without an error.

On a side note: I apparently cannot use StyleCopAnalyzers since it is not compatible with VS versions below 2015.

**Question:**

How can this be solved? A solution that added a custom rule to 'StyleCop by Resharper' would be the most elegant, I think. But really, at this point any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think the option to have a blank line after a *single If line* is under 
 Code Editing > C# > Formatting Style > Blank Lines in Code > After Statements with control transfer and set it to 1

AFAIK the only way to add new custom rules to Stylecop (doesn't matter if is the one from R# is by doing the following -> https://www.planetgeek.ch/2009/07/19/custom-stylecop-rules-2/